# jFrame multiple event listeners on one button

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm quite new to the whole GUI scene of Java but I decided to give it a try. I have a project in NetBeans and I am using their little auto generator thing and was wondering if you can have multiple even listeners on one button? Right now I have it so when you click it changes the button to a certain color and I was wondering if you can make it so when you click it again, it changes the color back to the default color?

This is what my button looks like right now

```
     private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        jButton1.setBackground(Color.black);
        jButton1.setForeground(Color.yellow);
     }
```

I have an idea of how it would look but I can't really get it to work. I know you have to set it back to the regular color like this.

```
    jButton1.setBackground(null);
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a check in your event listener to see if the color is already changed:

```
if(jButton1.getBackground().equals(Color.black)) {
    ... // revert color
} else {
    jButton1.setBackground(Color.black);
    jButton1.setForeground(Color.yellow);
}
```

Comment: Would I be able to make it change it back to the default color on a click of the button?

Comment: Yes did you try that?

Comment: I could be completely implementing this wrong but it does not seem to be working for me.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working. Stupid little mistakes on my part. Thank you so much!